# rule validation with Operator c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am comparing two String arrays Operator(AND, NOT AND, NOT OR, OR) combinations for rule validation. Though I am able to write the scenarios for AND and NOT AND Operator combination with some inbuilt Intersect(), SequenceEquals methods but not able to do it for "OR" with "NOT OR" and "AND" with "NOT OR" combination.

Below is the scenario:-

1) `String str1 = new String[]{ "Element 1", "Element 2" };`

It could have a combination of Element 1/Element 2/Element1 & Element 2.

2) `String str2 = new string[]{ "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4"};`

It could have a combination of Element 1/Element 2/Element3/Element4.

The attached image([validation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOSou.jpg)) has the result of "AND" and "NOT AND" Operator combination for the string arrays and I used `if (!Str1.SequenceEqual(Str2))validation = false;` to do the validation.

Similarly, I would like to do the validation for the same combination using "OR" with "NOT OR" and "AND" with "NOT OR" with simple logic. Please help me to share your thoughts on my case.

Comment: `String str1 = new String[]` is not legal syntax. Is it a `string` or a `string[]`?

Comment: This question really does not explain what `NOT AND` and `NOT OR` means. In each line in your image, there are two operators. What does that mean? One would expect `someList someOperator someList = someResult;`, but the image does not portray that.